# soap api able to connect in SoapUI but not in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I've been failing to consume a soap webservice with soapClient /nusoap I believe the issue might be with my header but I'm not sure as the error I get back are pretty vague at times.
We've been able to get it to work in SoapUI, which adds some additional things to the header notably this:

```
<wsa:Action>http://www.property24.com/services/IP24ListingServiceWcf/FetchAgents</wsa:Action><wsa:To>https://www.exdev.property24.com/Services/P24ListingService46.svc</wsa:To>
```

Its being added in SoapUI automaticaly by checking:     add default WSA:to    under WS-A

inside the header it also has xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" I dont know how to correctly set this if possible.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://www.property24.com/services">
   <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <ser:CredentialsHeader>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:EMail>..</ser:EMail>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:Password>..!</ser:Password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:UserGroupEmailId>1</ser:UserGroupEmailId>
      </ser:CredentialsHeader>
   <wsa:Action>http://www.property24.com/services/IP24ListingServiceWcf/FetchAgents</wsa:Action><wsa:To>https://www.exdev.property24.com/Services/P24ListingService46.svc</wsa:To></soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <ser:FetchAgents>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:agencyId>..</ser:agencyId>
      </ser:FetchAgents>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm getting a bad request response which I believe could be due to the header
this is what I've tried:

```
$headerbody = array(
        'EMail' => $username,
        'Password' => $password,
        'UserGroupEmailId'=> $groupId
);

$headers[] = new SoapHeader('https://www.exdev.property24.com/', 'wsa:Action', "http://www.property24.com/services/IP24ListingServiceWcf/$method");
$headers[] = new SoapHeader('https://www.exdev.property24.com/', 'wsa:To', "https://www.exdev.property24.com/Services/P24ListingService46.svc");
$headers[] = new SoapHeader('https://www.exdev.property24.com/', 'CredentialsHeader', $headerbody);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
```

and

```
 $header_part = '<CredentialsHeader><EMail>....</EMail><Password>....</Password><UserGroupEmailId>1</UserGroupEmailId></CredentialsHeader>';
    $header_part .= '<wsa:Action>http://www.property24.com/services/IP24ListingServiceWcf/$method</wsa:Action><wsa:To>https://www.exdev.property24.com/Services/P24ListingService46.svc</wsa:To>';
    $soap_var_header = new SoapVar($header_part, XSD_ANYXML, null, null, null);
    $soap_header = new SOAPHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing', 'wsa', 
    $soap_var_header);
    
$client->__setSoapHeaders($soap_header);
```

I've not had a lot of experience with Soap webservices and have been stuck on this for quite some time thanks guys

Comment: are you able to consume in SoapUI ?

Comment: yes the soap envelope i posted is from SoapUI, I'm thinking if I can get the php version to match theirs it will work

Comment: check the below answer I experienced the same before and this scenario work with me

Answer (score 0):

construct header object by concatenating with user credentials

```
 $headerStr=  '
    <ser:CredentialsHeader>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <ser:EMail>'.$username.'</ser:EMail>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <ser:Password>'.$password.'</ser:Password>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <ser:UserGroupEmailId>'.$groupId.'</ser:UserGroupEmailId>
 </ser:CredentialsHeader>
<wsa:Action>http://www.property24.com/services/IP24ListingServiceWcf/FetchAgents</wsa:Action><wsa:To>https://www.exdev.property24.com/Services/P24ListingService46.svc</wsa:To>
    ';

    $header= new \SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing',
        'wsa',
        new \SoapVar($headerStr, XSD_ANYXML), 
        true
    );
```

then construct SoapClient and set headers and operation name with parameters

```
$soapclient = new SoapClient($serviceURL,$options);
$soapclient-> __setSoapHeaders($header);
```

parameters can be sent as dictionary but very important to chang "Request" to be identical to the same name in service contract

```
 $param=array ("Request" => array('agencyId'=>'123'));
    $response =$soapclient->FetchAgents( $param);
    var_dump(json_encode($response));
    echo '<br><br><br>';
    $array = json_decode(json_encode($response), true);
    print_r($array);
```

the complete code snippet will be

```
try {
    $options = [
        "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2, // SOAP_1_1
        'trace' => 1,
        'exception' => 1,
        'keep_alive' => false,
        'connection_timeout' => 500000
    ];
    $headerStr =  '
    <ser:CredentialsHeader>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <ser:EMail>' . $username . '</ser:EMail>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <ser:Password>' . $password . '</ser:Password>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <ser:UserGroupEmailId>' . $groupId . '</ser:UserGroupEmailId>
    </ser:CredentialsHeader>
    <wsa:Action>http://www.property24.com/services/IP24ListingServiceWcf/FetchAgents</wsa:Action><wsa:To>https://www.exdev.property24.com/Services/P24ListingService46.svc</wsa:To></soap:Header>
    ';
    $header = new \SoapHeader(
        'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing',
        'ws',
        new \SoapVar($headerStr, XSD_ANYXML),
        true
    );
    $soapclient = new SoapClient($serviceURL, $options);
    $soapclient->__setSoapHeaders($header);
    $param = array('agencyId' => '123');
    $response = $soapclient->FetchAgents($param);

    // print the last XML request to compare with the working one in soapUI
    echo "REQUEST:\n" . $soapclient->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
    var_dump(json_encode($response));
    echo '<br><br><br>';
    $array = json_decode(json_encode($response), true);
    print_r($array);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I've updated with the above its similar to what I tried, though my param is much different I've changed it to what you suggested:  param = array("FetchAgents" => array('agencyId' => '13286'));   Its still giving a "Bad Request"  could it be something else causing a bad request? they supplied us with a .cer file and instuctions to install in the browser I'm not sure how that fits in the bigger picture though

Comment: no this is the right way to set header and parameters but one last thing for URL add ?wsdl at the end of URL

Comment: http://www.exdev.property24.com/Services/P24ListingService46.svc?wsdl but ensure that it is working on browser first

Comment: also install certificate by double click on cer file and it will be installed automatically

Comment: Hi I previously added the certificate to keychain and made it trusted, it also shows up alright in the browser when viewed https://www.exdev.property24.com/Services/P24ListingService46.svc?wsdl

Comment: I can't check from my side because I don't have a certificate however I did small modifications in method parameters and line to print last to soap XML just compare the generated soap from PHP with the generated one from SoapUI